# Aurelia validation working but not displaying validation messages

Tags: aurelia

I have `aurelia-validation` (**version 0.6.3**) setup and blocking the form submission when calling `this.validation.validate().then () => {...}`, but no validation message is displayed on the UI, neither when the value of a field changes nor when the validation blocks the form submission, which I would expect based on [the Aurelia Validation examples](http://aurelia.io/validation/)

**main.js**

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin("aurelia-animator-css", settings => {
            settings.duration = 200;
        })
        .plugin("aurelia-computed")
        .plugin("aurelia-dialog", (settings) => {
            settings.lock = true;
            settings.startingZIndex = 5;
        })
        .plugin("aurelia-validation", (config) => {
            config.useLocale("nl-NL");
        })
        .feature("components/tinyMCE")
        .globalResources("components/typeahead");

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

**editSku.js**

```
import{inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import EditableSku from "../models/editableSku";
import {Validation} from "aurelia-validation";

@inject(Validation)
export class EditSku {
    constructor (validation) {
        this.validation = {};

        this.sku = new EditableSku();
        this._setupValidation(validation);
    }

    save() {
        this.validation.validate().then(() => {
            // ...work some magic here...
        });
    }

    _setupValidation(validation) {
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensure("sku.articleCode")
                .isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

**editSku.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#general-tab" data-toggle="tab">General</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" submit.delegate="save()" validate.bind="validation">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="general-tab">

                        <!-- The field to validate is in this view -->
                        <compose view="./templates/sku-general-tab.html"></compose>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" disabled.bind="validation.isValidating">Save</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

**templates/sku-general-tab.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="articleCode">
            Article code
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" show.bind="isNew">
            <input type="text" value.bind="sku.articleCode" class="form-control" id="articleCode" name="articleCode" placeholder="Article code">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

As you can see, I bind the validation to the form on the `editSku` view, and the input to be validated are actually on the composed `general-sku-tab` view. I've also tried setting the field to be validated outside of the `compose` element and that didn't work either.

Again, the call to validation in the `save` method works as expected, no `<p>` elements are inserted with the validation messages.

FWIW, I'm using [the SB Admin 2 Bootstrap theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/). I would expect this to maybe mess up the styling (even though most of the styles are the actual Bootstrap 3 styles), but not to prevent `aurelia-validation` to insert the messages into the DOM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the aurelia-validation is looking for the class `form-group` for the current element to be validated:

https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/strategies/twbootstrap-view-strategy.js#L69

https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/strategies/twbootstrap-view-strategy.js#L16

As user5246190 suggested in her answer aurelia-validation is looking for a `Label`element **but within a element with the class `form-group`**

Answer (score 1):

***Aurelia Looks For label element to print the validation messages on your View/UI***

```
<div class="form-group fg-float fg-line" show.bind="isNew">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fg-input" dvalue.bind="sku.articleCode" class="form-control" id="articleCode" name="articleCode" placeholder="Article code">
   <label class="fg-label"></label>
</div>
```